# jmeter-analysis-plugin IllegalArgumentException: Null or zero length 'values' argument

Tags: maven, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am getting an illegal argument exception when running the jmeter-analysis plugin. I have validated all the output ***.jtl*** files and it doesn't appear that the xml files are malformed. Below I have posted the maven command I am using to run the performance test suite ***(which runs fine)***, as well as my project structure, pom and output. I can't quite figure out what is going on, as everything was actually working before I updated the JMeter test plan in the .jmx. The suite runs fine in the JMeter GUI and runs fine before it gets to the analyze step. Has anyone encountered this before? What can I do to solve this?

**Maven**

```
mvn -pl performance-tests clean verify -U -X
```

**Project Structure**

```
Project
    Performance Test Module
        src
            test
                jmeter
                    performance-tests.jmx
            resources
                properties
                    artifact_headers.properties
                    artifact_users.properties
                index.html
```

**POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>artifact-id</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.group.id</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>performance-tests</artifactId>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>default</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <threads>1</threads>
                <loops>1</loops>
                <ramp>1</ramp>
                <delay>1</delay>
                <account></account>
                <password></password>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <properties>
        <com.artifact.jmeter.test>${project.basedir}/src/test/jmeter/*.jmx</com.artifact.jmeter.test>
        <com.artifact.target.environment>https://dev-dot-api-dot-labs-horizon-1.appspot.com</com.artifact.target.environment>
        <com.artifact.jmeter.loops>${loops}</com.artifact.jmeter.loops>
        <com.artifact.jmeter.threads>${threads}</com.artifact.jmeter.threads>
        <com.artifact.jmeter.ramp>${ramp}</com.artifact.jmeter.ramp>
        <com.artifact.jmeter.startup.delay>${delay}</com.artifact.jmeter.startup.delay>
        <com.artifact.jmeter.account>${account}</com.artifact.jmeter.account>
        <com.artifact.jmeter.password>${password}</com.artifact.jmeter.password>
        <reportdirectory>${project.build.directory}/results</reportdirectory>
        <kg.apc.version>1.4.0</kg.apc.version>
        <commons.lang.version>2.6</commons.lang.version>
        <net.minidev.version>2.3</net.minidev.version>
        <surefire.version>2.19.1</surefire.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vault</groupId>
            <artifactId>vault-lib</artifactId>
            <version>2.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
            <version>${net.minidev.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>${commons.lang.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>kg.apc</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-plugins-standard</artifactId>
            <version>${kg.apc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>kg.apc</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-plugins-extras</artifactId>
            <version>${kg.apc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <customPropertiesFiles>
                        <file>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/bin/properties/artifact_headers.properties</file>
                        <file>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/bin/properties/artifact_users.properties</file>
                    </customPropertiesFiles>
                    <propertiesFilesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/bin/properties</propertiesFilesDirectory>
                    <jmeterExtensions>
                        <extension>commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6</extension>
                        <extension>net.minidev:json-smart:2.3</extension>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-standard:1.4.0</artifact>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-extras:1.4.0</artifact>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-extras-libs:1.4.0</artifact>
                        <artifact>org.apache.jmeter:jorphan:3.0</artifact>
                    </jmeterExtensions>
                    <propertiesUser>
                        <jmeter.loops>${com.artifact.jmeter.loops}</jmeter.loops>
                        <jmeter.threads>${com.artifact.jmeter.threads}</jmeter.threads>
                        <jmeter.ramp>${com.artifact.jmeter.ramp}</jmeter.ramp>
                        <jmeter.account>${com.artifact.jmeter.account}</jmeter.account>
                        <jmeter.password>${com.artifact.jmeter.password}</jmeter.password>
                        <RESULTS_PATH>${reportdirectory}</RESULTS_PATH>
                    </propertiesUser>
                    <propertiesJMeter>
                        <aggregate_rpt_pct1>80</aggregate_rpt_pct1>
                        <aggregate_rpt_pct2>90</aggregate_rpt_pct2>
                        <aggregate_rpt_pct3>99</aggregate_rpt_pct3>
                    </propertiesJMeter>
                    <overrideRootLogLevel>warning</overrideRootLogLevel>
                    <testResultsTimestamp>false</testResultsTimestamp>
                    <!--<resultsFileFormat>csv</resultsFileFormat>-->
                    <resultsDirectory>${reportdirectory}</resultsDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <id>thread</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>analyze</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!--<source>${project.build.directory}/**/*.jtl</source>-->
                            <source>${reportdirectory}/performance-tests.jtl</source>
                            <targetDirectory>${reportdirectory}/generatedreport</targetDirectory>
                            <sourceDirFailed>false</sourceDirFailed>
                            <checkResult>
                                <throughput>
                                    <threshold>-1</threshold>
                                    <toleranceDirection>UPPER_LOWER_TOLERANCE</toleranceDirection>
                                    <tolerance>5</tolerance>
                                </throughput>
                                <errors>
                                    <threshold>-1</threshold>
                                    <toleranceDirection>UPPER_LOWER_TOLERANCE</toleranceDirection>
                                    <tolerance>5</tolerance>
                                </errors>
                            </checkResult>
                            <configurationCharts>
                                <width>950</width>
                                <height>500</height>
                            </configurationCharts>
                            <maxSamples>50000</maxSamples>
                            <preserveDirectories>false</preserveDirectories>
                            <sampleNames>
                                <sampleName>sample</sampleName>
                                <sampleName>httpSample</sampleName>
                            </sampleNames>
                            <processAllFilesFound>true</processAllFilesFound>
                            <remoteResourcesFromUntilDateFormat>HH:mm_yyyyMMdd</remoteResourcesFromUntilDateFormat>
                            <writers>
                                <!--<com.lazerycode.jmeter.analyzer.writer.SummaryTextToStdOutWriter/>-->
                                <!--<com.lazerycode.jmeter.analyzer.writer.SummaryTextToFileWriter/>-->
                                <!--<com.lazerycode.jmeter.analyzer.writer.HtmlWriter/>-->
                                <!--<com.lazerycode.jmeter.analyzer.writer.DetailsToCsvWriter/>-->
                                <com.lazerycode.jmeter.analyzer.writer.DetailsToHtmlWriter/>
                                <com.lazerycode.jmeter.analyzer.writer.ChartWriter/>
                            </writers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/bin</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${pom.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Stack Trace**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin:1.0.6:analyze (thread) on project performance-tests: Error analysing: Null or zero length 'values' argument. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin:1.0.6:analyze (thread) on project performance-tests: Error analysing
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error analysing
    at com.lazerycode.jmeter.analyzer.AnalyzeMojo.execute(AnalyzeMojo.java:233)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null or zero length 'values' argument.
    at org.jfree.data.statistics.HistogramDataset.getMinimum(HistogramDataset.java:221)
    at org.jfree.data.statistics.HistogramDataset.addSeries(HistogramDataset.java:136)
    at com.lazerycode.jmeter.analyzer.writer.ChartWriter.createResponseTimesPlot(ChartWriter.java:188)
    at com.lazerycode.jmeter.analyzer.writer.ChartWriter.writeCharts(ChartWriter.java:95)
    at com.lazerycode.jmeter.analyzer.writer.ChartWriter.write(ChartWriter.java:65)
    at com.lazerycode.jmeter.analyzer.ResultAnalyzer.analyze(ResultAnalyzer.java:47)
    at com.lazerycode.jmeter.analyzer.AnalyzeMojo.analyze(AnalyzeMojo.java:318)
    at com.lazerycode.jmeter.analyzer.AnalyzeMojo.execute(AnalyzeMojo.java:217)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue on some cases. For me it seems to be linked to results where all requests fail with errors. That is I have zero successful requests.

Answer (score 1):

```
I have downloaded the plugin and see the exception is happening with ChartWriter component when it doesn't have 'values' to generate charts (I think).

To by-pass it without changing code, you can disable ChartWriter (if you not really need it) by changing in pom as below.

<plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-html-report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <processAllFilesFound>true</processAllFilesFound>
                            <source>${project.build.directory}/**/*.jtl</source>
                            <writers>
                                <com.lazerycode.jmeter.analyzer.writer.SummaryTextToStdOutWriter/>
                                <com.lazerycode.jmeter.analyzer.writer.SummaryTextToFileWriter/>
                                <com.lazerycode.jmeter.analyzer.writer.HtmlWriter/>
                                <com.lazerycode.jmeter.analyzer.writer.DetailsToCsvWriter/>
                                <com.lazerycode.jmeter.analyzer.writer.DetailsToHtmlWriter/>
                                **<!--<com.lazerycode.jmeter.analyzer.writer.ChartWriter/>-->**
                            </writers>

                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>analyze</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggled with this issue for while, finally figured it out.

I installed JMeter-3.2, but copied a jmx file created during version-3.1. After I created a new jmx file under new version, it works.

Not sure you had same experience. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

*Remark: This is not an direct answer to the question, but a possible solution to the given exception of jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin.*

In my case all tests fail because of server errors (unauthorized). So you first should check the jtl file (here performance-tests.jtl) for valid entries:

```
<httpSample t="329" lt="329" ts="1551219503246" s="false" lb="/" rc="401" rm="Unauthorized" tn="performancetest 1-6" dt="text" by="932" ng="9" na="9"/>
```